# VB6: Comparing a cell from Excel to a string from text box

Tags: string, excel, vb6

I' m new to VB6 and I would like to compare a string from a text box with a cell from excel. I use

Dim temp1 As String

Dim temp2 As String

temp1 = A.Text

temp2 = wsheet.Cells(l, 3)

i = StrComp(temp1, temp2, vbTextCompare)

but The result is never 0 as the function need. The text is in form x.x.x.x and I copy paste it from excel in the text field.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks you in advance!!

Comment: Can you should where/how your are defining "A"?  My guess is that is the root of the problem.

Comment: @Myles A is the text box name

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub myCompareText()
    Dim temp1 As String
    Dim temp2 As String
    Dim i As Integer
    temp1 = ActiveSheet.A.Value
    temp2 = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value
    i = StrComp(temp1, temp2, vbTextCompare)
    MsgBox "The vbTextCompare Result is: " & CStr(i)
End Sub
```

Please reply if this worked and mark this answer to be a Complete Answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now. I added trim function, but it didn't solve the issue. I realize that when I copy paste a cell from Excel the length of string is the length of string +2. I typed the key I was looking for in the text field and it works fine. Thank you for your help and in case you know something about this I would appreciate to read it.

Thank you!!